Screenshot of the Week #122 - Romance
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 122nd edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Batophobia's screenshot from little-kitty-big-city won with 14 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-08-19, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-08-26, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Romance
Living in the sunlight, loving in the moonlight, having a wonderful time!
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

"Gaga, ooh-la-la"

There's a lot of romance in video games, and yet strangely enough I didn't have many screenshots worth sharing

Shien and Aska on a beach in Shien's Revenge.

shien-revenge

This is yet another SNES game. It's akin to an FPS because you have to throw ninja stars at enemies that either come after you or "shoot" projectiles against you (which you have to block using your knife). It's a short but relatively difficult game.

I hesitated to cut off the black bars, but since it's part of the cutscene I figured I'd leave them in there.

By the way, I have no idea how to pronounce that name.

Tidus and yuna in final-fantasy-10


When I saw your name pop up, I almost knew it was a picture of Tidus & Yuna

Oh i have some Others in Store.
